# Type problems with tuples & streams

Tags: java, lambda, tuples, java-stream, keyvaluepair

I have my own implementation for a few tuples, here's the gist of the code for pair:

```
public class Pair<A, B>  extends Tuple implements Serializable{
    ...
    public Pair(A a,B b){
        this.a=a;
        this.b=b;
    }
    ...
    public <T> Pair<T,B> mapA(Function<A,T> fun){
        return new Pair<T,B>(fun.apply(a),b);
    }
    ...
}
```

For some weird reason the following code does not work and the compiler seems to think that the resulting pair from the first mapping is `<Object,String>`.

```
List<Pair<String,String>> pairs = ...;
pairs
.stream()
.map(p->mapA(s->s.trim())
.map(p->mapA(s->s.toUpperCase()) //does not recognize a as a string
...
```

Could this be also Eclipse acting up? Running Eclipse Luna fwiw which seems to do a shitty job in general in determining generic types from functional interfaces.

EDIT: full example as requested

```
public class Pair<A, B> implements Serializable{
    public final A a;
    public final B b;

    public Pair(A a,B b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    public <T> Pair<T,B> mapA(Function<A,T> fun){
        return new Pair<T,B>(fun.apply(a),b);
    }

}


List<Pair<String,String>> pairs = new ArrayList<>();
pairs.add(new Pair<String,String>("foo","bar"));
pairs.stream()
.map(p->p.mapA(s->s.trim()))
.map(p->p.mapA(s->s.toUpperCase()))
.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Can you provide a complete and reproducible example?

Comment: sec... also tried casting fun.apply(a) to T

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis  forgot to hilite

Comment: Must be an eclipse issue ... no complains and errors in NetBeans ... did you try at least just compiling and running?

Comment: Compiles fine in Eclipse for me.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis luna or mars?

Comment: Version: Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2)
Build id: 20150219-0600

Comment: k, I'm one version behind with 
Version: Luna Service Release 1 (4.4.1)... I'll try installing Mars tomorrow and see if that helps

Comment: try IntelliJ instead.

Comment: Meh, having had to use Android Studio has kinda traumatized me for life.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated to Eclipse Mars and the issue is completely gone.

Answer (score 4):

Type inference for a typed method doesn't work with lambdas.

Also, you have a coding error (you were referencing the `mapA()` method without an instance).

You can fix the problem by explicitly typing the method:

```
pairs.stream()
.map(p -> p.mapA(s -> s.trim())) // input type is known here from stream
.map(p -> p.<String>mapA(s -> s.toUpperCase())) // but not here
```

Although only a style issue, you could rewrite the above using method references:

```
pairs.stream()
.map(p -> p.mapA(String::trim))
.map(p -> p.<String>mapA(String::toUpperCase))
```

Comment: Works for the example but for some reason not for my actual use case. Triplet<String,Long,Ref> triplets ...; triplets.stream().mapC(MyItem::load).<MyItem>mapC(MyItem::getTitle) ... Complains that getTitle is not defined for object. i->i.getTitle() wont work either.

Comment: I could obviously do something like mapC(r->MyItem.load(ref).getTitle()), but I'd kinda need to map the triplets to <String,String,MyItem> elsewhere anyways.

Comment: Now the example is not working either anymore... darn eclipse... EDIT: turns out it works when using `p.mapA(String::trim)` but not with `p.mapA(s->s.trim())`... The real life case fails with both tho

Comment: This one did the trick: `triplets.stream().map(t->t.<MyItem>mapC(MyItem::load).map(t->t.mapC<String>(MyItem::getTitle))`...